# cref reference format for label type `' undefined

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I have this error that I suspect comes from the fact that my tables and figures are in a slave file. It seems that `cleveref` does not manage to see the "class" of my float. I tried with `varioref` and I have a similar issue, I tried to put the `\includegraphics` before the text, I updated my TeXLive...  Any help is welcome.

Here my example (sorry if it's not following the proper rule but it's my first time with a question).

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape, rotating} 
\usepackage{tabu, longtable} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref, varioref, cleveref}
\usepackage[xindy, acronym, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\begin{document}

Before running any analysis we first checked for collinearity or correlation 
among variables and did not notice any specific relationship (scatterplot 
not shown).

We present here scatterplot matrix of data grouped by theme: presence data 
(\vref{Pevex8r}), CPUE data (\vref{Cevex8r}) and time and location data 
(\vref{TLevex8r}).

As \gls{CPUE} data are severely skewed, we transformed them using a $log$ 
transformation: $\log($\gls{CPUE}$+1)$ (\vref{CTevex8r}). 

\include{figure_Recap1}
\end{document}
```

Here is what my slave file looks like:

```
\begin{figure}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\includegraphics{../../R/Data_exploration/Plots/Pevex8r.pdf}
}
\label{Pevex8r}\caption{Scatterplot matrix of species presence variable} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\scalebox{0.7}{
\includegraphics{../../R/Data_exploration/Plots/TLevex8r}
}
\label{TLevex8r}\caption{Scatterplot matrix of time and location variable} 
\end{figure}
```

etc...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: A side comment: When loading the `varioref`, `hyperref`, and `cleveref` packages, it's best to load them in this order. (In your example code, you load `hyperref` *before* `varioref`.)

Comment: @Mico: You just solved my 100%-CPU hang problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to put the `\label` command *after* the `\caption`. Then, both `\vref` and `\cref` will work.

The reason for the error is that `cleveref` and `varioref` cannot determine the type of the label unless `\caption` is issued first. Putting the label *after* the caption will tell `cleveref` and `varioref` that the object's type is, in both of the examples you give, `figure`.

Comment: +1 isn't this true for *any* `label` and `ref` though (not just `cref` and `vref`)?

Comment: @cmhughes Yes, of course, but the error message in the title of the question refers to the broken type inference. Put differently, other `\ref`-like commands will also not work correctly, but won't show this error, sometimes not even an error at all.

Comment: @XochitlCORMON If this solves your problem, may I ask you to accept the answer?

Comment: I had this problem because I was using `caption*{}` to suppress figure numbering.

Comment: I had this problem because I was using `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` to suppress section numbering.

Comment: I had this problem, but it got away by removing `\usepackage {varioref}` (because I anyway only used `cleveref`).

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error message was resolved by trying yet another ordering of loading the three packages varioref, cleveref and hyperref:

1. varioref
2. hyperref
3. cleveref

Source: https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing section "Interpackage interactions for varioref, hyperref, and cleveref"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I placed my `\crefname` statement inside my document instead of in my preamble. (The location with the preamble may also matter; see the other answers).

Comment: The code in the question doesn't include `\crefname`, does it? What does 'my `\crefname` statement' refer to?

Comment: That's a command from the `cleveref` package that defines the displayed names of environments. The situation I described is not the problem the OP had, but if other people are having this same error, then they are likely to arrive at this page.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same error, but I resolved it by defining the "theorem" environment that was causing trouble in the preamble *after* loading `cleveref`. Namely, the preamble should have the following lines in this order:

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{coro}{corollary}
```

and not the other way around.