# revtex4-2: cref reference format for label type `' undefined

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, revtex

I'm having issues getting cleveref to recognize references when using revtex4-2. When compiling, all references give a warning "LaTeX Warning: cref reference format for label type `' undefined on input line ..." and fail to typeset correctly. I've seen [cref reference format for label type `' undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102490/cref-reference-format-for-label-type-undefined), as well as a number of issues regarding cleveref and appendix sections on this site, but my issue is seems unrelated because switching to revtex4-1 fixes the problem in my case. Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass[aip]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\label{sec:first}

Hello

\section{Second section}

Hello \cref{sec:first}

\end{document}
```

As expected, I have to run pdflatex twice to get the references right, but once I do everything renders correctly. However, if I replace the documentclass with `revtex4-2`, then the contents of the "Second section" read "Hello ??". I'm running on Mac OS and I've updated all my packages using Tex Live Utility, so I don't think it's a versioning issue, but rather something in how `revtex4-2` is redefining some internal TeX macros. Unfortunately I don't know enough to dig into the details there.

**EDIT**
One extra piece of information that may be useful to future viewers of this issue: adding the `hyperref` option to the list of documentclass options *does not* resolve this issue. However, avoiding that option and instead explicitly writing `\usepackage{hyperref}` (before `\usepackage{cleveref}`) does resolve the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a full solution, but hopefully a satisfactory work-around: Load `hyperref` before `cleveref`. (If you don't want colored hyperlinks, load `hyperref` with the options `colorlinks` and `allcolors=black`.)

I browsed the contents of `revtex4-2.cls`. It looks like somebody made an effort to change the default properties of LaTeX's `\label` macro, possibly to make life easier for `hyperref`, which does its own furthering doctoring of `\label`. By loading `hyperref`, this further doctoring is accomplished, thereby making way for `cleveref` to do its own, additional doctoring of `\label`.

In sum, what appears to be going on is that the `revtex4-2` document class has changed the properties of `\label` in a such way that `cleveref` can no longer apply its own further patches successfully; hence the `??` output. By loading `hyperref` as well, the properties of `\label` get changed further, but happily in a such way that `cleveref` once more knows what to do. (Aside: If `hyperref` and `cleveref` are both loaded, it is well known that `cleveref` must be loaded *after* `hyperref`. It was this piece of knowledge that led me to investigate whether loading `hyperref` might provide a work-around for the problem at hand...)

[image]

```
\documentclass[aip]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} 

\begin{document}
\section{First section}\label{sec:first}
Hello.

\section{Second section} \label{sec:second}
Hello \cref{sec:first}.

Hello \crefrange{sec:first}{sec:second}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great call! I specifically removed hyperref because I knew about the interaction and wanted to create a minimal example, and it didn't occur to me that hyperref could actually fix the problem. Would you consider this a bug that I should report to the maintainers of revtex, or is this likely to be the expected behavior going forward?

Comment: @Vyas - Thanks. I'm not in a position to judge whether the revtex42 modifications amount to a bug. (FWIW, if I were in charge of their LaTeX coding, I'd definitely apply the mods to the `\label` macro only if the `hyperref`` package were loaded.) If you want to contact them and draw their attention to the fact that their modifications to the `\label` macro make the basic revtex42 document class code incompatible with the `cleveref` package, I would assume that they'd very much appreciate learning about this issue.

Comment: I sent them an email letting them know about this issue.

Comment: I've tried the above solution with loading hyperref but it's not solving the problem: ```
text \Cref{a} ... \section{s_a}
\label{a}
``` shows ```Section``` without a number. Using: Debian testing pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 cleveref 2018-03-27 revtex 4.2a Any suggestions?. Thanks

Comment: @jzz11 - Thanks for alerting me to this issue. It would appear that the workaround I suggested in the answer shown above, which I posted more than 2 years ago, no longer works an with up-to-date version of the LaTeX format file. Not sure why. All I can surmise is that the extended hook management methods LaTeX started providing in the fall of 2020 have something to do with this mess. For sure, I can't get the test document shown above to compile correctly inmy MacTeX2022 distribution (pdfTeX Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24, LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5). Truly sorry I can't say more.